# Push changes in git submodule to main module but not to submodule

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a git project A that uses a submodule B from Github. I cannot push to the Github project B because it is not mine. I want to do a small change in B that is not pushed to the remote B (because I can't push) but it should be pushed to A (so when someone uses A, he should be able to see my changes).
I tried to commit in B, then commit in A and it seems like the changes are committed correctly. When I push A to bitbucket it shows me the submodule with a new commit.
I tried to clone A somewhere else, but I get the following error:

```
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref 7b9e40769855bc50f3be629cd8307d76dd8ecf1b
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Fetched in submodule path 'src/B', but it did not contain 7b9e40769855bc50f3be629cd8307d76dd8ecf1b. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

I guess the new commit couldn't be found because it was not pushed to the remote of B.
Is there any way around this?
I'd prefer to keep B as a submodule so I can get updates from the remote project but I also need these small changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share it, you somehow have to publish it.

One way is :

- on github: fork project `B`
- publish the commit you want on your fork
- in project `A`: update the git module remote url to point to your fork, and use the commit id for the commit you created.

At a later time, if the changes you want are integrated to upstream `B`, you can switch back to the original base url for project `B`.

---

Another option, if you are ok with it, is, in your next commit on `A`, to stop handling `B` as a submodule, and integrate it as a subtree of your repo.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there no way to commit the changes I made in B only to the representation of B in A?

Comment: Updated my answer : you can also start using `git subtree` to handle that dependency.

Comment: I am glad someone was having the same question as I have now. This is basically what I want: 1) embed a submodule (which is someone else's project that I don't have access to) in my own repo 2) within submodule directory, I should be able to easily pull latest change from other project 3) if I made some local changes on the submodule, I want to push it to my own parent repo only 4) I should be able to view the content of changes made in submodule in github