# Tweaking a submodule in Git

Tags: git, git-submodules

Suppose I have a repo `parent` and a repo `child`, where the latest is a submodule of the first one.

My `child` repo is being maintained by a third party. I would like to keep track of the most recent updates made by this third-party while also doing my own specific changes to this submodule to make it compatible with my parent repo.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant way to use submodules, but I have this exact situation and I handle it by `cd`-ing into the submodule and handling it from there as a classic Git repo.

This way, it is easy to set my own fork of the `child` project as `origin` and the original `child` project as `upstream`. I can pull from `upstream` to get the latest updates from the original project (maintained by a third party), make my own changes and push them to `origin` so that they can be shared.

To update the `parent` repo, I simply stage and commit the changes to the submodule.

In order to know what changes were made to the submodule from the `parent` project when I commit those changes, I have, in my git config file:

```sh
[diff]
    submodule = log
```

This will show the log of the submodule when running diff operations from within the `parent` project. It is not necessary, but it is convenient as I don't have to go down to the submodule to know what I have done, etc.

You can set this locally by running `git config diff.submodule log` from your `parent` repo or you can set it globally with `git config --global diff.submodule log`.

Note that you get the same result by running `git diff --submodule` from your parent repo instead of `git diff` (if you don't want to play with your config files).

Comment: That's the propper way! just remember to `git add /your/submodule/path` before commiting your `parent`

Comment: @prosoitos : this works perfectly well for local handling, do you have a way to share the changes you make on your local clone of the submodule ?

Comment: Yes: I simply push them to `origin` (my fork of the original `child` repo) from within the `child` repo. When I am in this situation, I almost treat my submodules as nested Git repo. I still keep them as submodules though (even if I don't manage them entirely from the `parent` repo) as there are little benefits.

Comment: @prosoitos : ok (just saw the `origin`/`upstream` part in your answer)

Comment: @prosoitos Do you actually set up your own fork of the `child` repo first? So you have a `parent` repo containing a `child` repo that points to your fork set earlier? I'm asking this ecause when I try to commit directly into my `child` repo that points to the original project, the `git push` command (launched from within the submodule) tries to update the original project. So I don't know how to tell git to keep these changes only for the current project (`parent`).

Comment: What do you mean by "original project"? I am a bit confused by your question here.

Comment: @prosoitos The "original project" is the one maintained by the third-party, where I only have read access.

Comment: You have to push to `origin` (your fork to which you have write access) and not to `upstream`. Run `git push -u origin master` (adapt as needed based on your remotes and branch names). It sounds that you have set the wrong upstream. This has nothing to do with the submodule question though.

Comment: Now I understand your question. Yes, you first have to create a fork. *Then* you clone the fork. Because when you clone a repo, Git automatically sets that as the default remote called `origin` that you can push to with `git push` without having to use `-u` (or `--set-upstream`). But again, that has nothing to do with submodules.

Comment: Ok so yeah I can't run the command `git submodule add /path/original/submodule` (original child project) in my `parent` repo. I need to first create a fork of the original child project then run from my `parent` repo : `git submodule add /path/myFork/submodule`. Then any changes (updates from third-party or specific to my project) are handled from the fork That's it?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. Git will automatically make your fork the default remote for push/fetch and will call it `origin`. You have to add the 3rd party original project as `upstream` however so that you can pull from it (if you want to bring in updates). Note that you could also do what you had done and then re-set which remote is which with the `--set-upstream` flag. But that is not a classic workflow and I would stick to the common workflow to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64390808/86072) asked almost the same thing, with some way to *publish* the changes. Here is an additional way :

Another option, if you are ok with it, is, in your next commit on `parent`, to stop handling `child` as a submodule, and integrate it as a subtree of your repo.